# Compare two different columns from two different tables and show other column's data from either table in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Compare two different columns from two different tables with if statement and show other column's data from either table in laravel 5.2

controller like:

```
public function labDetails(){
    $users = DB::table('users')->lists('lab_name');
    $labdetails = Labdetails2::paginate(20);
    return View('labdetails')
            ->with('users', $users)
            ->with('labdetails', $labdetails);
}
```

here i want to match users table's 'lab_name' column with labdetails2 table's 'lab_name' column and if they matched show only the related data from labdetails table.

**N.B.** I am working with an old database where there's no relationship among tables.

views like:

```
  <form action="" method="">
  <select name="state" onchange="getValue(this)">
      <option value="">Select Lab</option>
      @foreach ($users as $key => $user)
      <option value="{{ $user }}">{{ $user }}</option>
      @endforeach 
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">

      @foreach ($labdetails as $labdetail)
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>{{ $labdetail->sl }}</td>
          <td>{{ $labdetail->lab_name }}</td>
          <td>{{ $labdetail->pc_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $labdetail->pc_ip }}</td>
            <td>{{ $labdetail->mac1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ $labdetail->assetno }}</td>
            <td>{{ $labdetail->pc_type }}</td>
            <td>{{ $labdetail->processor }}</td>
            <td>{{ $labdetail->motherboard }}</td>
            <td>{{ $labdetail->ram }}</td>
            <td>{{ $labdetail->hdd }}</td>
            <td>{{ $labdetail->location }}</td>
            <td>{{ $labdetail->department }}</td>
            <td>{{ $labdetail->entrydate }}</td>
            <td>{{ $labdetail->comment }}</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      @endforeach
```

Please help me what should I do with the controller & views...

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve only the matches record this way

```
$users = DB::table('users')->lists('lab_name'); // this retrieves all lab_name as array.
```

Then, to retrieve only the matches `labdetails`

```
$labdetails = Labdetails2::whereIn('lab_name',$users)->paginate(20);
```

Comment: thank you so much, whereIn() actually worked for me after requesting select option. but paginate() providing some RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST')) error though get() worked nicely.

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('users')
            ->join('labdetails2', 'users.lab_name', '=', 'labdetails2.lab_name')
->select('labdetails2.lab_name', 'labdetails2.pc_name')
->get()
```

in select(), white down the fields you required.

Here, **labdetails2**  and **users** are the table name.

Comment: thanks, so far i have managed to get all data by this process but i also want to match the data after submitting. my target is when 'users.lab_name' is submitted it will show all the matched data from 'labdetails2.lab_name'. for example when  'users.lab205' =  'labdetails2.lab205' then it will show all the data of 'labdetails2.lab205'. need also bit help regarding views.

Answer (score 0):

this code finally worked for me:

```
public function showLabDetails(Request $request){

    $q = $request -> request -> all();

    $labdetails = Labdetails2::whereIn('lab_name', $q)->get();

    return View('showlabdetails')
            ->with('labdetails', $labdetails);
}
```

thanks to everyone for helping me.